# What is 'build-env' in a dockerfile definition?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and I'm following Microsoft's tutorial for building a .net core console app with docker at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows

This is the docker file definition for a simple Hello World app

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DotNet.Docker.dll"]
```

In the above example, what is `build-env` from this line `COPY --from=build-env /app/out .` ?
I tried google, but no relevant articles are returned and can't find any help in the official docs either.

In the tutorial page it says

> The COPY command tells Docker to copy the specified folder on your
> computer to a folder in the container. In this example, the **publish**
> **folder** is copied to a folder named app in the container.

I assume the author means we copy the contents of */app/out* to the */app* folder, as there is no folder named */publish*. So the destination folder is defined by the previous line: `WORDIR /app`. When I initially read `COPY --from=build-env /app/out .` I assumed it copies from */build-env* to *app/out* but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Also, what is the purpose of the `COPY . ./` line?

Comment: build-env is an alias to mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

Comment: Thanks! The alias syntax in the first line didn't catch my eye.

Comment: COPY --from=build-env /app/out . copies /app/out from build-env based container to The `WORKDIR /app` on the new image or on container that will be built from it.

Comment: Can you expand your comments to an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Alright, let me do that.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build-env` this context is just an alias to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0` image.

The syntax to create an alias for an image is as follows:
`[image_name] AS [Alias]`

Now you can use the Alias instead of the lengthy image name in your Dockerfile.

`COPY --from=build-env /app/out .` copies /app/out from build-env based container to The WORKDIR /app on the new image that will be built from this dockerfile.

`COPY . ./` will copy the contents of the directory where this dockerfile is located to the `WORKDIR /app` on the new image that will be built from this dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

build-env is defined in the first line of the dockerfile: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

The copy . ./ means to copy all files from src location (current) to destination (./) . You can get more details on dockerfile in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/